# WooCommerce remove shopping cart by user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

In Woocommerce, I have a function that replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in shop and archive pages:

```
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
if ( ! current_user_can('customer') ) {
    $link = get_permalink($product_id);
    $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
    $html = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">'.$button_text.'</a>';
}
return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'conditionally_change_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```

I would like to remove the add to cart button on all pages if a user is not logged in as a customer.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your actual code, try the following that will do everything everywhere and will remove add to cart button when user is not logged in:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Thank you but I have still one problem when I add this. I thought this would also fix it but apperently this was not the problem.   

I hide product image based on user role "customer" and this works but for the variable products when I select the variable then the image reappears.

Any idea how to fix this? Or maybe to hide the product variations when the user is not a customer?